# Horizontal line with a mulitiple color and a label in flutter? Who know how to draw this ? Im new in flutter

Tags: flutter

benter image description, here

[image: Horizontal line with multiple color]

Comment: We may, can trick this by using stack and inviable slider or just using gesture detector. btw do want slider or just drawing?

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: just drawing but the circle is based on the given value. i need some paratemer

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's no attempt to code it

Comment: @MengChengteoh At Stack Overflow we work on the policy that the user must show an attempt before getting assistance. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help.

Comment: Thank for helping big god, im refering your code and do some changes Thank for help. This is very helpful for me

Comment: @HardcoreGamer noted, i have tried before, but i have no idea to draw this, then i post At the stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

**Result**

[image: output]

You may need to align some property based on style, you can also use stack for `Text`.

**Painter**

```
class Sliderpaint extends CustomPainter {
  final double value;

  final double gapPercentage = .02;
  final double circleRadius = 10;

  Sliderpaint({
    required this.value,
  });

  Color circleColor() {
    if (value <= .25)
      return Colors.green;
    else if (value <= .5)
      return Colors.blue;
    else if (value <= .75)
      return Colors.yellow;
    else
      return Colors.red;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double dCY = size.height / 2;

    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 4;

    canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(0, dCY), Offset(size.width * (.25 - gapPercentage), dCY), paint);
    canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(size.width * .25, dCY),
        Offset(size.width * (.5 - gapPercentage), dCY),
        paint..color = Colors.blue);
    canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(size.width * .5, dCY),
        Offset(size.width * (.75 - gapPercentage), dCY),
        paint..color = Colors.yellow);
    canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(size.width * .75, dCY),

        /// you can ignore it here
        Offset(size.width * (1 - gapPercentage), dCY),
        paint..color = Colors.red);

    canvas.drawCircle(
      Offset(size.width * value, dCY),
      circleRadius,
      paint
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
        ..color = circleColor(),
    );

    final textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: '18.5',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontSize: 18,
        ),
      ),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );
    textPainter.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: size.width * .25,
    );
    textPainter.paint(canvas, Offset(size.width * .2, dCY * .7));

    final textPainter2 = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: '25',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontSize: 18,
        ),
      ),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );

    textPainter2.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: size.width * .25,
    );
    textPainter2.paint(canvas, Offset(size.width * .47, dCY * .7));

    final textPainter3 = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: '30',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontSize: 18,
        ),
      ),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );

    textPainter3.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: size.width * .25,
    );
    textPainter3.paint(canvas, Offset(size.width * .72, dCY * .7));

    ///bottom Text
    final textPainter4 = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'Thin',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontSize: 12,
        ),
      ),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );

    textPainter4.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: size.width * .25,
    );
    textPainter4.paint(canvas, Offset(size.width * .1, dCY * 1.1));

    final textPainter5 = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'Healthy',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontSize: 12,
        ),
      ),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );

    textPainter5.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: size.width * .25,
    );
    textPainter5.paint(canvas, Offset(size.width * .3, dCY * 1.1));

    final textPainter6 = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'Slightly Fat',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontSize: 12,
        ),
      ),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );

    textPainter6.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: size.width * .25,
    );
    textPainter6.paint(canvas, Offset(size.width * .57, dCY * 1.1));

    final textPainter7 = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'Obesity',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
          fontSize: 12,
        ),
      ),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );

    textPainter7.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: size.width * .25,
    );
    textPainter7.paint(canvas, Offset(size.width * .82, dCY * 1.1));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

**TestWidgte to use this painter**

```
class TestC extends StatefulWidget {
  TestC({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestCState createState() => _TestCState();
}

class _TestCState extends State<TestC> {
  double sliderVal = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Slider(
                value: sliderVal,
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      sliderVal = v;
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              CustomPaint(
                painter: Sliderpaint(value: sliderVal),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 400,
                  height: 200,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**More interesting way to control**

```
CustomPaint(
                painter: Sliderpaint(value: sliderVal),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 400,
                  height: 200,
                  child: Opacity(
                    opacity: 0,
                    child: Slider(
                        value: sliderVal,
                        onChanged: (v) {
                          setState(() {
                            sliderVal = v;
                          });
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

[customSliderUI on repo](https://github.com/yeasin50/Dart_-Flutter_Advanced/blob/master/lib/Utils/custopPaints/customSliderUI.dart)